# Initializaton error in com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, extent

I am running the script using Cucumber in BDD Framework and I am using Extent Reports plugin to create the execution report.

I've created the test runner class as below:

```
package com.ctl.it.qa;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = { "src/test/resources/Feature/ABC.feature" 
},

plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:BDDControlCenterTools/target/Reports/cucumber-report.html"}
)
public class RunCukes {

}
```

I have included the below dependency for the Extent report in the POM.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am running the script with Junit and have the cucumber dependency for Junit too.

But when I execute the above runner class, its showing an Initialization error:
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter

Can anyone please help in this error and help to resolve it.

Comment: seeknig help to resolve this error

Comment: You are missing the import statement for extent report. please add the following line in your import section. import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

Answer (score 4):

You need to also add the Maven dependency for this formatter. Refer to this -- https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter documents.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

But i think this only works with ExtentReport version 3 and above.

Comment: I tried to add this Dependency and run the script, but it display a run time exception error:

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aventstack/extentreports/reporter/ExtentHtmlReporter

Comment: It works only with ExtentReport version 3 and above. Use a latest version of ExtentReport... -- Check the article from the plugin author - http://www.vimalselvam.com/cucumber-extent-reporter/

Answer (score 3):

I was having com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter initialization error but after few tweaks. I can generate the report now.

I added these two to my POM file. The version can be tricky as I used 3.1.1 for cucumber-extentreport but it didn't work for me. After trying a few 3.0.2 worked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My runner class looked like this:

```
package cucumber;

import java.io.File;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)  
@CucumberOptions(   
        features = {"src/test/resources/features", 
        glue = {"stepDefinitions"}, 
        plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"},
        monochrome = true
        )

public class CucumberRunner {
        @AfterClass
        public static void writeExtentReport() {
            Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/report.xml"));
        }   
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different version of cucumber-extentsreport. For me, the latest version (3.1.1) did not work, but 3.0.2 did.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this.
Remove below code "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html" from the runner class and then run the runner class.
It will run successfuly. Then put this back into the runer class and execute, it will work.